# Type inference from Prisma with Zod

Tags: typescript, prisma, nodemailer, next-auth, zod

Here is my prisma model for User

```
model User {
    id            String    @id @default(cuid())
    name          String?
    email         String?   @unique
    emailVerified DateTime?
    image         String?
    accounts      Account[]
    sessions      Session[]
}
```

I am infering type using zod-prisma package as a result it generates the following code

```
import * as z from "zod"
import { CompleteAccount, RelatedAccountModel, CompleteSession, RelatedSessionModel } from "./index"

export const UserModel = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  name: z.string().nullish(),
  email: z.string().nullish(),
  emailVerified: z.date().nullish(),
  image: z.string().nullish(),
})

export interface CompleteUser extends z.infer<typeof UserModel> {
  accounts: CompleteAccount[]
  sessions: CompleteSession[]
}

/**
 * RelatedUserModel contains all relations on your model in addition to the scalars
 *
 * NOTE: Lazy required in case of potential circular dependencies within schema
 */
export const RelatedUserModel: z.ZodSchema<CompleteUser> = z.lazy(() => UserModel.extend({
  accounts: RelatedAccountModel.array(),
  sessions: RelatedSessionModel.array(),
}))
```

Now I need to use `CompleteUser` as a type to send an email with `nodemailer`

```
    const sendWelcomeEmail = async (user: CompleteUser) => {
  try {
    const result = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"⚡ Magic NextAuth" ${env.EMAIL_FROM}`,
      to: user.email,
      subject: 'Welcome to Magic NextAuth! ',
      html: `<div></div>`
    }
    );
    const failed = result.rejected.concat(result.pending).filter(Boolean);
    if (failed.length) {
      throw new Error(`Email(s) (${failed.join(", ")}) could not be sent`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error

`Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | Address | (string | Address)[] | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Address | (string | Address)[] | undefined'.t`

for this line `to: email,`

I comprehend that the type must not be `null`. To address this issue easily, I can utilize the type `email: string` or changing zod schema to `email: z.string().optional(),`to fix it.

To make things more complicated I have to use this function with `next-auth` here is the code

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
    signOut: '/',
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: env.EMAIL_FROM,
      maxAge: 10 * 60,
      sendVerificationRequest(params) {
        const { identifier, url, provider } = params;
        const { host } = new URL(url);
        transporter.sendMail({
          to: identifier,
          from: provider.from,
          subject: `Sign in to ${host}`,
          text: text({ url, host }),
          html: html({
            base_url: env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
            signin_url: url,
            email: identifier,
          })
        }, (err, info) => {
          console.log(info);
          console.log(err);
          const failed = info.rejected.concat(info.pending).filter(Boolean);
          if (failed.length) {
            throw new Error(`Email(s) (${failed.join(", ")}) could not be sent`);
          }
        });
      },
    }),
  ],
  events: { createUser: sendWelcomeEmail },
  secret: env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

this line
`events: { createUser: sendWelcomeEmail },`

is giving me the following error
`Type '(user: CompleteUser) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(message: { user: User; }) => Awaitable<void>'. Types of parameters 'user' and 'message' are incompatible. Type '{ user: User; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CompleteUser': accounts, sessions, id`

Not really sure how to address it

Comment: I think yes, you're making it complex. Are you using Next.js? Then use t3 stack, it has all the types directly from prisma

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov I use t3 stack

Comment: so `@trpc/server` returns `inferRouterInputs` and `inferRouterOutputs` types. You can use it like:
`type ProjectsType = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>["project"]["getAll"]`

Comment: @A.Anvarbekov I get what you are saying but it does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution. Not perfect but at least it does work.

```
const isString = (value: unknown): value is string => {
  return typeof value === 'string';
};

const sendWelcomeEmail = async <T extends { user: User }>(message: T) => {
  try {
    if (message.user.email && isString(message.user.email)) {
      const result = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: `"⚡ Magic NextAuth" ${env.EMAIL_FROM}`,
        to: message.user.email,
        subject: 'Welcome to Magic NextAuth! ',
        html: `<div>HELLO</div>`
      }
      );
      const failed = result.rejected.concat(result.pending).filter(Boolean);
      if (failed.length) {
        throw new Error(`Email(s) (${failed.join(", ")}) could not be sent`);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('errorrr:', error);
  }
}
```

events provided by `next-auth`

```
events: {
    createUser: async (message) => {
       await sendWelcomeEmail<typeof message>(message)
        // typeof message is equal to {user: User}
     },
  },
```

let me know if we can make it better.